# JavaScript Immediately push to array inside 'new function()'

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, constructor, push

I'm new to JS (and programming), so forgive me if my terminology is incorrect. I have run searches based on the way I can think about this, which may be faulty, and I have not found what I'm looking for.

The following code works to build up my charList array. However, is there a way to include a charList.push(x) inside of the constructor in order to immediately and automatically push a new character to the array when I run the **new character()** constructor-function?

```
var charList = [];

function character (name, jobTitle) {
  this.name = name;
  this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}

charList.push(new character("Sarah", "Nurse"));
charList.push(new character("Bob", "Doctor"));
console.log(charList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
charList.push(this);
```

in the constructor.